# Refreshing a parent page after closing a ModalPopupExtender using only C#

Tags: c#, modalpopupextender

Is it possible to refresh a parent page after you close a ModalPopupExtender using only C#?  I don't know Javascript much and I'm confused by the Javascript answers I've seen online, and can't find anything that uses just C# to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a little strange, but have you considered this approach?

In your case, you would detect if the panel's client id's visible property has changed.

When the popup is closed, the property of the panel should change to hidden.

you use a mutation observer.

[MutationObserver and current/computed CSS styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364687/mutationobserver-and-current-computed-css-styles)

Comment: i had to change it to use a mutation observer, but the idea is the same