# Detect Vue component' slot position and size changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-slot

I have a component which receive named slots:

```html
<Child>
    <template #content>
        <p>tooltip content</p>
    </template>
    <template #activator>
        <button>hover me</button>
    </template>
</Child>
```

I wanna know the position and size of the activator slot no matter where I'm gonna use it and what I'm gonna do with it. If I do like this:

```js
<template>
    <div style="margin-top: 13px;" :style="styleObject">
        <Child>
            <template #content>
                <p>tooltip content</p>
            </template>
            <template #activator>
                <button>hover me</button>
            </template>
        </Child>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {reactive, ref} from "vue";
import Child from "./components/Child.vue";

const styleObject = reactive({
    marginLeft: '16px'
})

setTimeout(() => {
    styleObject.marginLeft = '30px'
}, 2000)
</script>
```

Inside `<Child>` component I want to detect position changed after 2 seconds. I was able to get initial position and size with this:

```js
const slots = useSlots()

const activatorStyles = reactive({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    height: 0,
    width: 0
})

const getActivatorStyles = () => {
    if (slots?.activator) {
        activatorStyles.top = slots.activator()[0]?.el?.offsetTop
        activatorStyles.left = slots.activator()[0]?.el?.offsetLeft
        activatorStyles.height = slots.activator()[0]?.el?.offsetHeight
        activatorStyles.width = slots.activator()[0]?.el?.offsetWidth
        console.log('activatorStyles', activatorStyles)
    }
}

onUpdated(getActivatorStyles)
onMounted(getActivatorStyles)
```

but I'm not sure how to detect that in any of the parent components something changed which resulted in this `<Child>` component position or size change. For example this timeout from snippet above.

I was trying onUpdate but this seems to be working only on DOM Nodes changes (not styles). I was also trying to make this object as a computed property but no luck. [Here is vue playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) where initial size and position is correctly gathered but after timeout execution it doesn't detect that `left` changed and it stays `24`.

My question is how can I can keep my `activatorStyles` object up-to-date no matter what will happen in parent components?

---

**EDIT:** I tried MutationObserver on parent but problem is that I don't know from where the changes of position / size might come. If I observer `parentElement` as suggested it works very well if the styles binding are on direct parent. If you I have more `<div>` nested and style binding is happening somewhere deeper the mutationObserver is not triggering anymore. To make it work I would need to pass `document.body` to observer which is not best performance, isn't it? [playground example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqVVUtvm0AQ/isbejCWDDit1AMhjqKoUg+JckiqHkoPGIZHCuxqd8hDlv97Z3cBvyuXg9nd2e+b1zd45dwK4b924IROhNCIOkFYxC2jJ8qqV6bwo4br2GkSWVSth1yE7PKLeL+KHRYORvN+XL5AirHToy1+3ND2rqzqbOvAHA4+2aeUtwgt7l0wl8QCOa+xEqy/FAVinyjYi/6IhyTF6jVBLo/5WHaIvF2U/BUkayAK+oMz3ETBbmpRsMl8WO8AaatSWQlkCrATrE7agsqIylSvagSXyFYSTMAwYxLyNcslb1jsUK9i52q8ZTwPNt8Govtp7sQt1UuRl01/2DWxWV53ZUO0rb2HHEM2ufwq3idxu55qNEX3XDXAO3TdKbtesB6xxedv0EQ9+TyfW/yM0XJOLFFgU6XEnJljo/aaRPgvirekOkMZ9wYqQDg46VMNaVEiChUGgcpTnduL8rksAlr5smuRIvRBNd5S8jcFkohjZ7bFEdAhNdWT0GYgQf6Lc+/qAa+mXVN6lMpY6oPRiS48j7HnXrJ3VrKMeZ61qpoja5NGT06vZxqm4Aj0dhDscfCo5w1cSFisVqPhSTdKrdc0L2TYU+H/abBT8ES+1Yzx9oFT2SHTyx8iI7bsQJ6j9DSGlDHAXSMsa9sL84g0zedm3jezNgoddiVURbm1f6syLGk7aNe6SJO6XibpH+LeUrC28Rr8mhfuRPEGsKzagqUl1QAusgkRUJMHjgJwbMQY6c48VDlzTaI3/pjTdDDqZy9Tn/IiDgPZINzpr/nvGx/qG5/nuZ49Lk5T6GqcwaEH8zSJLeIZNN/NxdNEpvpn8PzU9zY0O40YUReWdDI7SeeLhEYUv9XQ0IvaZemoZzRnAzEyvrTzTIG18MYeOkyw4u1jf+wO6phqwe4g6TevCsKtWIIoK/ozABUylB2NQqon/75SpD57oLolSgC7ZWti6+PBIQK/X7gZTzsds7/k2QdRGT9GsBqgPy16Pc6Veyg+ujxO4HHz7kd3/RdHTKII)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component will only update if its props/data/computed changed. What happens there is that the update happens on the parent.

If you simply just want to access the parent from child, just use the `$parent` property and check/watch the property that holds the style.

Docs: https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#parent

**NOTE**:

`$parent` is a reference to whatever **Vue** component rendered your component.

```
<A>
  <B />
</A>
```

In this example, `B`'s `$parent` would be `A`.

If you're going to teleport/move the element manually to another element, then what you want is

```
$el.parentElement
```

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp

---

Another option would be to check DOM changes via `MutationObserver` or using library like https://popper.js.org/

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559787/10975709

---

My opinionated answer though would be to suggest encapsulating the idea of styling the parent as part of your component that way your component can safely check that prop always.

Your example looks similar to some of Vuetify components like the `Dialog` for example (because of the activator slot).

Vuetify encapsulates the responsibilities everything on its own and doesn't rely on the code of whoever uses it.

Docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/#usage

Comment: This is component from components library that is exported as a package so I don't really even know the parent and I can't control it. In my case there's requirement to teleport one slot content to body and bind to it correct styles basing on #activator slot element position. MutationObserver is nice but it requires to specify element on which attributes we want to observe isn't it?

Comment: Yes it requires what element to observe. If you're teleporting the element then this changes the whole thing. `$parent` refers to the Vue component that rendered the `<Child/>` . If you want the DOM element that holds the activator, then that would be `$el.parentElement`

Comment: Please take a look at my edit

Comment: If the component cannot work without the parent's styling, then it's part of the component. How Vue works is you pass down props and receive data via events (except for edge-cases). Here's a popover component made by headlessui for inspiration: https://headlessui.com/vue/popover